# PHP, why do I get an extra print at the end?

Tags: php

```
<?php
$VarC = 6;
$VarD = 2;
$ctA = 1;
$ctB = 2;
$VarAns = 0;
$VarAns = $ctA * ($ctB+$VarC) / $VarD;
do {
    do {
        $VarAns = $ctA * ($ctB+$VarC) / $VarD;
        echo ("X = $ctA * ($ctB + 6) / 2 is equal to: $VarAns<br>");
        $ctA = $ctA + 1;
    } while ($ctA <= 10);

    echo ("<br>");
    $ctA = 1;
    $ctB = $ctB + 2;
    $VarAns = $ctA * ($ctB+$VarC) / $VarD;
    echo ("X = $ctA * ($ctB + 6) / 2 is equal to: $VarAns<br>");
    $ctA = $ctA + 1;

} while ($ctB <= 10);

?>
```

I get an extra line at the end that I should not get, any ideas?
Im trying to print and stop when I reach 10, but it goes to 12!

I get

```
X = 1 * (2 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 4
X = 2 * (2 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 8
X = 3 * (2 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 12
X = 4 * (2 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 16
X = 5 * (2 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 20
X = 6 * (2 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 24
X = 7 * (2 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 28
X = 8 * (2 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 32
X = 9 * (2 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 36
X = 10 * (2 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 40

X = 1 * (4 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 5
X = 2 * (4 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 10
X = 3 * (4 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 15
X = 4 * (4 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 20
X = 5 * (4 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 25
X = 6 * (4 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 30
X = 7 * (4 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 35
X = 8 * (4 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 40
X = 9 * (4 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 45
X = 10 * (4 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 50

X = 1 * (6 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 6
X = 2 * (6 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 12
X = 3 * (6 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 18
X = 4 * (6 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 24
X = 5 * (6 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 30
X = 6 * (6 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 36
X = 7 * (6 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 42
X = 8 * (6 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 48
X = 9 * (6 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 54
X = 10 * (6 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 60

X = 1 * (8 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 7
X = 2 * (8 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 14
X = 3 * (8 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 21
X = 4 * (8 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 28
X = 5 * (8 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 35
X = 6 * (8 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 42
X = 7 * (8 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 49
X = 8 * (8 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 56
X = 9 * (8 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 63
X = 10 * (8 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 70

X = 1 * (12 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 9
```

The last line `X = 1 * (12 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 9` should not be there

Comment: how do I fix it? If i could use a while loop only i would, but I have to do it in a  do while

Comment: If you **have to us a `do while`**, then I assume your professor wants you to think about it and work it out for yourself.

Comment: @RiggsFolly The problem is not **do/while**, is the final echo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the while loop, it is that your initial code doesn't work and you has used a trick.

The nested do/while produce 10 lines at first primary do/while loop, but only nine at following loops, so you have added an additional `echo` before closing primary loop to “anticipate” next loop: this echo is performed even in the last loop, then the additional unexpected line.

Simply change `$ctA = 1;` in `$ctA = 0;` (in the loop) and remove the final `echo`:

```php
$VarC = 6;
$VarD = 2;
$ctA = 1;
$ctB = 2;
$VarAns = 0;
$VarAns = $ctA * ($ctB + $VarC) / $VarD;

do {
    do {
        $VarAns = $ctA * ($ctB + $VarC) / $VarD;
        echo ("X = $ctA * ($ctB + 6) / 2 is equal to: $VarAns<br>\n");
        $ctA = $ctA + 1;
    } while ($ctA <= 10);

    echo ("<br>\n");
    $ctA = 0; // <----------------
    $ctB = $ctB + 2;
    $VarAns = $ctA * ($ctB + $VarC) / $VarD;
    $ctA = $ctA + 1;

} while ($ctB <= 10);
```

<kbd>**[3v4l.org demo](https://3v4l.org/5mR2k)**</kbd>

Comment: As I understand it, Im doing it how im supposed to:  Write a program to do the algebraic equation x = a(b+6)/2 multiple times within loops that vary a and b. The variable a should start at 1 go to 10 and increment by 1. The variable b should start at 2 and go to 10 and increment by 2. When you display the answer show the formula in php. I want you to do this three times: once with a for...next, once with a do...while and once with a while.

Comment: This looks like homework. **We are not supposed to help with homework** its basically cheating on your behalf

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Comment: Im pretty sure Im allowed to ask for help on this, its not like im asking anyone to do my work for me, my work just needs some help, not asking for all of it. Also I do appreciate all the help so far.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
do {
    ....
} while (...);
```

do:

```
while(..){
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that it prints following lines?

```
X = 10 * (8 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 70

X = 1 * (12 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 9
```

Because your code should output:

```
X = 10 * (8 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 70

X = 1 * (10 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 8
X = 2 * (10 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 16
...
X = 10 * (10 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 80

X = 1 * (12 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 9
```

Look at condition when `$ctA == 1`and `$ctB == 8`. When execution enters:

```
do {
    $VarAns = $ctA * ($ctB+$VarC) / $VarD;
    echo ("X = $ctA * ($ctB + 6) / 2 is equal to: $VarAns<br>");
    $ctA = $ctA + 1;
} while ($ctA <= 10);
```

It will print:

```
X = 1 * (8 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 7
...
X = 10 * (8 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 70
```

at last iteration of inner loop, `$ctA == 10`, so after increase by 1, now `$ctA == 11`, then it exits inner  `do .. while`. Next, it enters:

```
echo ("<br>");
$ctA = 1;
$ctB = $ctB + 2;
```

It prints another break line, reset $ctA value to 1. Increase $ctB by 2. So now `$ctA == 1` and `$ctB == 10` and it enters:

```
$VarAns = $ctA * ($ctB+$VarC) / $VarD;
echo ("X = $ctA * ($ctB + 6) / 2 is equal to: $VarAns<br>");
$ctA = $ctA + 1;
```

which prints:

```
X = 1 * (10 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 8
```

Next, it increase $ctA value by 1, so now `$ctA == 2` and `$ctB == 10`. So condition `($ctB <= 10)` becomes true and outer `do .. while` is repeated once more. It then enters inner loop and prints:

```
X = 2 * (10 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 8
...
X = 10 * (10 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 80
```

It exits inner loop and print another break line and last output

```
X = 1 * (12 + 6) / 2 is equal to: 9
```

The problem is multiple call to this code:

```
echo ("X = $ctA * ($ctB + 6) / 2 is equal to: $VarAns<br>");
```

and not reset $ctA to 0.